# Homotopy equivalence iff weak deformation retract

Tags: algebraic-topology, retraction

This theorem is from page 29 in spanier's book. It is not detailed enough for me.

So,

In the first side, if $X$ and $Y$ are embedded as weak deformation retracts of $Z$, then we have the inclusion maps $i:X\subset Z$ and $j:Y\subset Z$ where $i$ and $j$ are homotopy equivalences. So there are $i':Z\to X$ and $j':Z\to Y$ such that
$i\circ i'=1_Z, i'\circ i=1_X$, same about $j$. Here $i', j'$ are retractions?

In the other direction, why is $r$ a homotopy equivalence and then $i$ is too?

Can I look at the inclusion map-embedding $j:Y\subset Z_f$ and the retraction $r:Z_f\to Y$ so $r\circ j=1_Y$ but what about $j\circ r$, don't I need to say it is homotopic to $1_{Z_f}$ ?

In theorem 12(a), $jr\simeq 1_{Z_f}$ rel $Y$, why this implies that  $j$ is a homotopy equivalence?

And they seem to use "embedding" as "inclusion" here..

Thanks for making it clearer to me.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TabLP.jpg)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnn0R.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $jr\simeq 1_Z$, then *both* $j,r$ are homotopy equivalences because we also have that $rj=1_Y\simeq 1_Y$.

Knowing $i:X\subset Z$ is a homotopy equivalence only means that $i'i\simeq 1_X,i\cdot i'\simeq 1_Z$, you don't necessarily have equality.

Knowing $ri=f$ is a homotopy equivalence and that $r$ is a homotopy equivalence implies $i$ is a homotopy equivalence.

> What about $j\circ r$, don't I need to say it is homotopic to $1_{Z_f}$?

You do, but the author has already shown this in $12a)$.

All embeddings are inclusions. Embeddings are just nice inclusions, ones that are homeomorphisms with their images. The author is just saying that these inclusions also happen to be nice ones.

Comment: In 12(a), we have a homotopy relative to $Y$, why this says that $jr\simeq 1_Z$? And $rj=1_Y$ since $r$ is a retraction, right?

Comment: @Bestmat The author explicitly write s a homotopy $jr\simeq1_Z$. I took the statement "$jr\simeq1_Z$" as a given from your own post.

Comment: @Bestmat Yes, $rj=1_Y$ just by definition ($r[y]:=y$)

Comment: Yeah, but in 12(a), the claim is that  $1_Z\simeq jr$ rel $Y$. So does it imply $jr\simeq 1_Z$?

Comment: @Bestmat (relative) Homotopy is an equivalence relation. This will have been explained much earlier in the book! $a\simeq b\iff b\simeq a$

Comment: I  mean that if it is a relative homotopy then it's a homotopy

Comment: @Bestmat Yes, a relative homotopy is also a homotopy. Why wouldn't it be? A relative homotopy $a\simeq b$ where $a,b:X\to Y$ is a map $H:X\times I\to Y$ with $H(x,0)=a(x),H(x,1)=b(x)$, *and also* some other condition. But ignoring that other condition, we still have $H$ is a homotopy $a\simeq b$

Comment: Yes! Thanks:) Just in the first side, it is enought to say, that if $iX\subset Z, j:Y\subset Z$ are homotopy equivalences then $X\simeq Z$ and $Y\simeq Z$ then $X\simeq Y$ by transitivity?

Comment: @Bestmat Yeah! ${}{}$